# JQuery UI Menu floating right icon causes new line in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I am having a JQuery UI Menu built pretty easy like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="..."><img src="icon.png" /></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="..."><img src="anotherIcon.png" /></a>
    <li><a href="..."><img src="thridIcon.png" /></a>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Menu is created with Script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu").menu();
});
```

What it should look like (and does in Chrome and Firefox):

[image: Correct displayed Menu]

What it looks like in Internet Explorer:

[image: Wrong displayed Menu]

I believe it has something to do with the floating right menu icon, but I have no Idea how to solve it.
Would be thankful if anybody had a solution or at least an idea how to approach.

Comment: Btw, when there is Text within the <a>-Tag instead of the image, everything is just fine, and displayed in a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found a solution myself:

HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="...">
    <img src="icon.png" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </a>
```

CSS:

```
li a img {
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

The CSS is in addition to the JQuery UI provided CSS.